# Toggle Inner Unordered List

Tags: jquery, css

Check this Fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/jVfj5/

What I am trying to achieve is that, when I click Services, The Sub Categories (The Nested Ul) should display, which is by default hidden. Also When I click Services, Only ul under Services should open, not all the other ul's together.

I can't get this work using jquery.

```
body
{
    background:rgba(115,115,115,1);`
}
}
ul.nav
{
    text-align:right;

}
ul.nav ul
{
display:none;   
}
ul.nav ul li{
background:rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
border-bottom:none;

}
ul.nav ul li:hover{
border-bottom:none;
background:rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
}

ul.nav a { 
    cursor: pointer; 
    display: block; 
    color: white; 
    line-height: 30px; 
    text-decoration:none; 
}
ul.nav li {
    text-transform:uppercase;
    margin-top:1.5%;
    padding-top:3%;
    padding-bottom:1%;
    padding-right:3%;
    background:#0c1026;
    border-bottom:5px solid green;

}
ul.nav li:hover{
border-bottom:5px solid red;
}
```

Html

```
<ul class="nav">
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="sub">Services</a></li>
                    <ul>
                      <li><a href="#">SubMenu1</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">SubMenu2</a></li>
                    </ul>  
                <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Our Library</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
            </ul>
```

Comment: Where is your current jquery? **However** you have closed the `.sub` `li` too soon. It should close **after** the submenu `ul`.

Comment: Your css has extra `}` at the start, your fiddle is missing jquery

Comment: Check the fiddle.. Its just experiment.. I am not well versed in jquery

Comment: @AbdulMuhaymin your fiddle does not have jquery included

Comment: Updated included jquery

Comment: I don't know if it's your typos or mistakes in the code but http://jsfiddle.net/jVfj5/5/ works. Your service `li` is closed too soon which created invalid html

Comment: @AbdulMuhaymin update question with the updated fiddle

Comment: @Huangism You are right.. but some answers given below works even without correcting it! Which is the correct way?

Comment: @AbdulMuhaymin Paulie has the correct answer, the main issue is you close the `li` at the wrong place which created invalid html structure and also make the jquery not work. Don't forget to get rid of the extra `}` after body tag or it will not look right

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The current Jquery works fine **if** you correct the HTML structure error

[**JSfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/jVfj5/14/)

**HTML**

```
<ul class="nav">
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="sub">Services</a>
                    <ul>
                      <li><a href="#">SubMenu1</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">SubMenu2</a></li>
                    </ul>  
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Our Library</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
            </ul>
```

Comment: Don't forget to get rid of the extra `}` after body tag

Comment: True but this will avoid OP asking another question about it

Comment: It affects the design. Because the background colour of main Ul is been displayed in sub ul which doesn't make sense in my case

Comment: @AbdulMuhaymin True but the issue was **functionality** not design. That's why there is no CSS in my answer...it wasn't relevant to the question.

Comment: Is there any issue if I don't follow that html rule? because if follow the other method, it works!

Comment: You HTML won't be valid and you run the risk of having it fail if the browser chooses not to interpret it. Now browsers are pretty forgiving (expept IE) so you might be Ok. The thing is....it's not very professional and if you don't do it the 'correct' way now...you'll do it wrong again. Learn good, clean, valid HTMl and it will save you having issues in the future. Plus..it will stop people like me reminding you every time. :) good luck.

Answer (score 2):

Change your js to this:

```
$('.sub').click(function() {
  $(this).parent().next("ul").toggle();
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jVfj5/8/)

Comment: Did you notice the current html is invalid? If you correct the html, problem = solved. The jquery is correct

Comment: @Huangism you are right. I just fixed the extra `}` in css. Didn't noticed html to be honest :)

Answer (score 0):

Set the `sub` class to the li item, not the `<a>` tag:

```
<li class="sub"><a href="#">Services</a></li>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jVfj5/10/

Answer (score 0):

I put a `div` around it and gave it an `ID`

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#nav ul li:not(:has(li.sub))").find("ul").hide().end().click(function(e) {
        if (this == e.target) {
            $(this).children('ul').slideToggle('fast');
        }
    });
});
```

## [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jVfj5/15/)